# How to keep last zero in php

Tags: php

This is my life problem how do I keep the last zero?

```
<?php
$x = 1456.20;
echo $x;//1456.2 but i need 1456.20
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)? Takes about 20 sec to search. Forgot about `number_format()` though =)

Comment: Taking the question at face value, the quickest way would be to convert it to string

Comment: Have you tried [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
<?php
echo number_format($x, 2);
?>
```

Comment: `number_format($x, 2, '.', '');` if you don't want the thousands separator.